# Jenkins Pipeline string and for-loop

Tags: shell, for-loop, jenkins, split, jenkins-pipeline

I'm creating a jenkins pipeline which has a string as a variable of 1 or more items

> text="test1.var1.eu-20190414121923517200000001
>   test2.var2.ue1-20190414121925623400000002
>   test3.var3.ue1-20190414121926583500000003"

I basically want to go in a loop and for each item run an action. for example echo each one in turn. The echo would look at the string and return each item in a for loop where there are 1 or more results

expected result:

> test1.var1.eu-20190414121923517200000001
>
> test2.var2.ue1-20190414121925623400000002
>
> test3.var3.ue1-20190414121926583500000003

I've tried a few things including adding a sh to run a for loop

```
#!/usr/local/bin/groovy

pipeline {
  parameters {
    choice(choices: "1\n2\n3", description: 'The length of time for the environment to remain up', name: 'hours')
  }

  stages {
    stage('get and update hours') {
      steps {
        script {
          env.text="test1.var1.eu-20190414121923517200000001 test2.var2.ue1-20190414121925623400000002 test3.var3.ue1-20190414121926583500000003"
          sh "echo ${text}"
          sh "for value in ${text}; do echo $value; done"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

expected result

> test1.var1.eu-20190414121923517200000001
>
> test2.var2.ue1-20190414121925623400000002
>
> test3.var3.ue1-20190414121926583500000003

actual result:

> [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
>   [Office365connector] No webhooks to notify
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: value for class: > groovy.lang.Binding
>     at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
>     at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:264)
>     at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
>     at  org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
>       at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)

Comment: What's the result you get now?

Comment: ```15:56:29 [test] Running shell script
15:56:29 + echo test1.var1.eu-20190414121923517200000001 test2.var2.ue1-20190414121925623400000002 test3.var3.ue1-20190414121926583500000003
15:56:29 test1.var1.eu-20190414121923517200000001 test2.var2.ue1-20190414121925623400000002 test3.var3.ue1-20190414121926583500000003
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[Office365connector] No webhooks to notify
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: value for class: ```

Comment: I have also tried below with the same error:

Comment: `
        script {
          env.text="test1.var1.eu-20190414121923517200000001 test2.var2.ue1-20190414121925623400000002 test3.var3.ue1-20190414121926583500000003"
          sh "echo ${text}"
          sh(script: "for value in ${text}; do echo $value; done", returnStdout: true).trim()
        }
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At which point you want to split this into particular texts? In general this part is missing `.split(' ')`.

```
def texts = text.split(' ')
for (txt in texts) {
    sh "echo ${txt}"
}
```

If you really want to do that in your shell directly add escaped quotes and use a variable

```
sh "test=\"${text}\";for value in $test; do echo $value; done"
```

Comment: the next thing i'm trying to do is generate 'text' from a call as below:

```
      env.ASG_GROUP_NAME = sh (script: """
      aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --region ${AWS_REGION} --query "AutoScalingGroups[? Tags[? Key=='Environment' && Value=='${ENVIRONMENT}']] | [? Tags[? Key=='Service' && Value =='${SERVICE_NAME}']] | [? Tags[? Key=='Env_Type' && Value =='${ENV_TYPE}']] | [? Tags[? Key=='Role' && Value =='${list[PMC_ROLE]}']]".AutoScalingGroupName --output text
      """, returnStdout: true).trim()
```

Comment: with the for loop, that returns the whole value and not split

Comment: if your original question was answered, please accept the answer and start a new question.

Comment: new thread opened https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56183311/jenkins-pipeline-output-from-aws-to-for-loop