# Jenkins pipeline Output from aws to for loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, for-loop, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline as below. I need the output from aws which returns multiple items to be split and used as individual items in a for loop which can be used to perform another action

i have tried `def ASG_GROUP_NAME toString()` as it seems it's not returning as a full string but with no luck

```
        def ASG_GROUP_NAME = sh (script: """
        aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --region ${AWS_REGION} --query "AutoScalingGroups[? Tags[? Key=='Environment' && Value=='${ENVIRONMENT}']] | [? Tags[? Key=='Service' && Value =='${SERVICE_NAME}']]".AutoScalingGroupName --output text
        """, returnStdout: true)
        sh "echo ${ASG_GROUP_NAME}"

        def texts = ASG_GROUP_NAME.split(' ')
        for (txt in texts) {
          sh "echo ${txt}"
        }
```

Expected:

```
09:52:45 [test] Running shell script
09:52:45 + echo test1.var1.eu-20190414121923517200000001
09:52:45 test1.var1.eu-20190414121923517200000001
[Pipeline] sh
09:52:45 [test] Running shell script
09:52:45 + echo test2.var2.ue1-20190414121925623400000002
09:52:45 test2.var2.ue1-20190414121925623400000002
[Pipeline] sh
09:52:45 [test] Running shell script
09:52:45 + echo test3.var3.ue1-20190414121926583500000003
09:52:45 test3.var3.ue1-20190414121926583500000003
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
```

Actual:

```
09:52:45 test1.var1.eu-20190414121923517200000001 test2.var2.eu-20190414121923517200000001 test3.var3.eu-20190414121923517200000001
```

Comment: you should get at least 2 echos, right?

Comment: right.. there should be 1 or more echo's returned

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but this might work, seems that you don't need delimiter in groovy for whitespace

```
def texts = ASG_GROUP_NAME.split()
for (txt in texts) {
  sh "echo ${txt}"
}
```